# Example of instance where the continuous functional calculus is really needed!

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I can't come up with an example where the holomorphic functional calculus is insufficient. Polynomials and power series seems to take us pretty far.

I am therefore looking for some scenario where we really need to apply a continuous function to an operator.

Comment: You can extend the idea of functional calculus to unbounded self-adjoint operators, where the naive definition a polynomial can be too "weak". Here the functional calculus gives the correct way to define $x^2$ etc. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770141/) old question of mine and its answer contain these thoughts with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting a square root of an operator is a technique that is used in a variety of contexts.  Square root is neither of polynomial nor of power series (at the origin) type.